# JPG vs WebP performance on Android

Tags: java, android, performance, webp

I´m trying to get performance stats about how Android load, decode and render WebP images against JPG, but my results are a little confuse.

Decoding WebP images to Bitmap are slow than JPG.

Some stats:

- WebP 66% less file size than JPG, 267% more time to decode.
- WebP 38% less file size than JPG, 258% more time to decode.
- WebP 89% less file size than JPG, 319% more time to decode.

Has someone know about any issue on performance, or why WebP decoding is harder than JPG.

This is my test:

```
public class BulkLoadFromDisk implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "BulkLoadFromDisk";

    private static final int TIMES = 10;

    private final ResourceProvider resourceProvider;
    private final Activity context;
    private final int counter;
    private long averageLoadTimeNano;
    private long averageConvertTimeNano;
    private final ImagesFactory.FORMAT format;
    private final CompleteListener listener;

    public BulkLoadFromDisk(Activity context, ResourceProvider resourceProvider,
                            CompleteListener listener, ImagesFactory.FORMAT format) {
        this.resourceProvider = resourceProvider;
        this.context = context;
        this.counter = resourceProvider.length();
        this.format = format;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        try {
            String file;
            long loadBegin, loadEnd;
            long convertBegin, convertEnd;
            Bitmap bitmap; Drawable d;
            String extension = "." + format.name().toLowerCase();
            InputStream inputStream;
            for(int j = 0; j < TIMES; j++) {

                for(int index = 0; index < counter; index++) {
                    file = resourceProvider.get(index).concat(extension);
                    inputStream = context.getAssets().open(file);

                    // Load bitmap from file
                    loadBegin = System.nanoTime();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    assert (bitmap != null);
                    loadEnd = System.nanoTime();

                    // Convert bitmap to drawable
                    convertBegin = System.nanoTime();
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
                    assert (d != null);
                    convertEnd = System.nanoTime();

                    averageLoadTimeNano += (loadEnd - loadBegin);
                    averageConvertTimeNano += (convertEnd - convertBegin);
                }

            }
            averageLoadTimeNano = averageLoadTimeNano / (TIMES * counter);
            averageConvertTimeNano = averageConvertTimeNano / (TIMES * counter);

            if(listener != null && context != null) {
                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listener.onComplete(BulkLoadFromDisk.this);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        catch (final IOException e) {

            if(listener != null && context!= null) {

                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listener.onError(e);
                    }
                });

            }

        } finally {
            System.gc();
        }

    }

    public interface CompleteListener {
        void onComplete(BulkLoadFromDisk task);
        void onError(Exception e);
    }

    public long getAverageLoadTimeNano() {
        return averageLoadTimeNano;
    }

    public long getAverageConvertTimeNano() {
        return averageConvertTimeNano;
    }

    public ImagesFactory.FORMAT getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public String resultToString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("BulkLoadFromDisk{");
        sb.append("averageLoadTimeNano=").append(Utils.nanosToBest(averageLoadTimeNano).first
                + Utils.nanosToBest(averageLoadTimeNano).second);
        sb.append(", averageConvertTimeNano=").append(Utils.nanosToBest(averageConvertTimeNano).first
                + Utils.nanosToBest(averageConvertTimeNano).second);
        sb.append(", format=").append(format);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Just for the sake of statistics, if you are using only 10 repetitions, you should increase it, say, to 1000. When I made a test to check if `++i` was faster than `i++`, I used a repetition of about 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and i haven't studied the in-depths of WebP yet, but it's probably because it's a more complex algorith, hence why it has better compression ratios than JPEG. WebP is based on the VP8 codec, which is itself an royalty-free competitor to the widely-used, and heavy, h264 format.

JPEG is widely used, however, it's a really old format and is considerably simpler than the VP8 codec of WebP.